# Can I combine 2 different data sources in the same Power BI dashboard?

Tags: windows, powerbi

From the first screenshot I do monitor the duration of customers using data from table1 out of my database:

[image]

On the second screenshot, I would like to do the same combining data from table2 and table1 but I keep getting a constant value for the duration. Has anyone tried a similar thing in Power BI Desktop (getting visuals with combined data source from two different tables)?

[image]

Adding a third screenshot of my tables structures in Power BI query mode. I would like to create the relationship such that all the data from the table `AttentionCollector2` can be monitored according to those of table `Weather_Forecast`

[image]

Comment: Screenshots alone without the table structures involved is really not helping to understand and solve the problem. Can you share or explain more?

Comment: I have just added another Image showing my tables structure. in the meant time I have been trying several Options to set the relationship between them. @FoxanNg